# AWS AppSync resolver cache layer?

Tags: caching, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

What is a common pattern to have AWS AppSync resolvers cache their output?

I'm writing an API that fronts data that will not change at all over time. The API returns the contents of books (title, author, chapters, etc.).

My initial idea was to have the resolver request some JSON payload from CloudFront. If the requested document is not in CloudFront, CloudFront would trigger a Lambda function, which would know how to fetch the JSON document (from a database), then put the payload in CloudFront. This seems weird conceptually, but it would solve the caching problem.

## Example

```
const query = `{
   bookById(bookID: "468c95") {
      bookID
      title
      author
      chapters {
         title
         text
      }
   }
}`;

const book = query(query);
// book => {
//   bookId: "468c95",
//   title: "AppSync for Normal People",
//   author: null,
//   chapters: [
//      {
//         title: "Chapter 1: Dawn of Men",
//         text: [
//            "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times.",
//            "..."
//         ]
//      },
//      { ... }
//   ]
// }
}
```

In other words, calling the fictitious `query` method will trigger some resolver in AppSync. That resolver will absolutely always return the same data. Thus, why not have the data that the resolver works with (I guess you can view that as the *input* to the resolver) be cached in CloudFront so it can be served from memory instead of having to hit some backend storage (like a database) or trigger a Lambda?!

Comment: It sort of feels like maybe AppSync resolvers aren't exactly the right tool for the task, but I have an incomplete picture of your use of AppSync.  Note that the solution you described isn't caching of resolver *output* -- it's technically caching of resolver *input*.  Also, you can't store things "in" CloudFront -- it's a pull-through cache for content from a separate origin server, like S3 or API Gateway or something running in EC2 or elsewhere on the web.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "caching in CloudFront." The resolver would attempt to fetch the object from a predetermined location. If that resolves in a 404, then CloudFront would trigger a Lambda that would fetch the data from somewhere, and return that object with proper cache headers, such that next request, CloudFront would have that object in its store.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, could you illustrate your use case with a example. Maybe with an example schema with resolvers and describe exactly what you are trying to cache and at what level.

Comment: Added an example...